# Changing row and column names on matrices to numbers

Tags: r

I'm constructing an adjacency matrix to use with the `bipartite` package. Each row and column represents an entity of two different classes, and `m[i,j]` represents an interaction between entity `i` of the first class and `j` of the second. I currently have a data frame `df` of the form

```
     s1   s2 weight
1   261  446      1
2   188  259      4
3   144 1119      1
```

where, for example, row 2 represents an interaction between member 188 of `s1` and 259 of `s2` of weight 4. So `m[259,188]` should be 4. However, since not every value between 1 and `max(df$s1, df$s2)` will be represented, using the normal indexes won't work. If it were possible, I'd want something like this:

```
        [,144] [,188] [,261] 
 [259,]      0      4      0
 [446,]      0      0      1
[1119,]      1      0      0
```

I know I can rename columns and rows to a character vector, but I think it would be inefficient/unwieldy to set it to `as.character(unique(df$s1))` (and similarly for `s2`) and index it that way. I also considered keeping a vector of the unique elements of `s1` and `s2` and using e.g. `m[which(unique.s2 == i), which(unique.s1 == j)]`, but again, that seems like a suboptimal solution. Since not every number between min(s1) and max(s1) will be in the matrix, I can't just make the dimensions c(max(s1), max(s2)) and use the indexes directly.

Is there a better way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: You describe something like sparse matrices. I think they should be present in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the row and column names as indices given as character.

First create the matrix with the sorted indices (s2 is rows as per your example).

```
s1 <- c(261, 188, 144); s2 <- c(446, 259, 1119)
m <- matrix(0, length(s2), length(s1), dimnames = list(as.character(sort(s2)), as.character(sort(s1))))

weight <- c(1, 4, 1)
m[cbind(as.character(s2), as.character(s1))] <- weight

     144 188 261
259    0   4   0
446    0   0   1
1119   1   0   0

m <- matrix(0, 261, 1119)
x[cbind(s1,s2)] <- weight
```

If you want `NA` rather than zero as the default value, replace it with `as.numeric(NA)`. 
You don't specify the number of rows or columns so I just used the maximum.

Comment: My problem is that the `bipartite` package (specifically the `specieslevel` function) expects a matrix, and doesn't work when passing in a sparseMatrix object.

Comment: Ok then, make the matrix() first, then update the non zero elements with x[cbind(s1,s2)] = weight

Comment: I changed my answer to suit, you should put this extra information in the question.

Comment: I think I was not clear in my post; I want s1 to be the column names, s2 to be the row names, and weight to be the elements. I've added a table to the OP.